# How can I used a WPF MVVM toolkit without an IoC container?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ioc-container, solid-principles

I've been doing S.O.L.I.D.-style programming even at the view-model level, but it's not gaining traction with other developers in the workplace. Their desire is to use MVVM Light or something like that. It's a bottom-up vs. top-down implementation dilemma that I'm trying to find a solution to.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to use features of an MVVM toolkit while avoiding an IoC container while continuing to use constructor parameters in view models to inject required parameters. What features of an MVVM toolkit could I benefit from without needing any global repositories?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I have to be honest, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here.  How is using an IoC container a violation of SOLID?  If anything, you can argue that constructor DI IS an IoC in and of itself since it passes the dependencies into the class, allowing the view model to maintain it's SRP while maintaining the D of SOLID.  Please help me understand what you're working towards.

Comment: The use of a global repository is a top-down technique, not a bottom-up one. In bottom up, each class is self-contained. SOLID helps create those cleanly reusable classes. It's a little beyond the scope of this question to discuss top-down vs. bottom-up.

Comment: However, if you are practicing bottom-up, you are not practicing constructor-driven DI, which is the 5th SOLID principle.  As a result, I don't understand what your question is actually attempting to accomplish.  And in short, if you really do intend to create self-contained bottom-up modules, then you don't want SOLID.  You want SOLI, or some other principle.  And finally, MVVM toolkit HEAVILY relies on managing inter-dependencies, since it is bridging the gap between the views and view models.  This seems to be yet another violation of bottom up.

Comment: What I am driving at is that there may not actually be a way for you to resolve your dilemma.  Either you use MVVM toolkit and it's benefits (including IoC) or you abandon it entirely to pursue a bottom-up approach without a global repository and binding mechanism.  I just don't see the two of them co-existing

Comment: How does a 'bottom-up', completely self-contained class get access to shared data (such as lookup data, say) if not from a global repository/source? You definitely don't want each class to implement their own version (not DRY) but you also don't want things tightly coupled. IoC and DI on interfaces is a common loosely coupled way to keep things SOLID.

Comment: By "self-contained," I mean that there are not side-effect behaviors like accessing globals. The dependencies are all right there in the public interface. It means that the same state type objects may be required by several classes. That's not violating DRY, it's just requiring a reference to the same instance of something in multiple places. Any ideas for my original question?